# Should I store hard-coded data in my Entity Framework data access layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a 3-layer application which utilize .NET Core EF as data access layer. Naturally, I on top of that have my business logic, which utilize the EF `Dbcontext` to perform database CRUD operations.

I'm in a situation now, where I want to be able to have objects of country and states, i.e.:

```
public class CountryAndStates
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public List<string> States { get; set; }
}
```

I have decided not to put this data in the database and thus hardcode it, as this is static data.

My question is now, where would I put this data in my application? Optimally, I guess it would be nice to somehow place the data in my data access layer, so that I can access it through my `DbContext` instance.

I am however unsure if this is a good idea. Therefore, I would like to know how this would be solved optimally, from a software architecture standpoint.

Comment: You should mask your CRUD operations behind a repository layer.  That respository layer should HIDE all the data stores: Databases, files, api calls to external providers etc....  The repository layer should be loosely coupled with the BL through interfaces.  Using DBContext directly from the BL is a  bad idea because now your BL depends on implementation details of your data access layer... there is no decoupling. Defeats the purpose of layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to pitch in my 2 cents on this.  Your Data Access Layer should HIDE the implementation of all the data stores: Databases, files, calls to external API's.

Your BL should never use DbContext directly and should not even know anything about it's existence; because this makes your BL dependent on an implementation detail which tightly couples your BL to your DAL...

What if you ever decide to not use Entity Framework any more?

What if you want to incorporate other data stores like json files or calls to external api's?

You see calling DbContext from your BL defeats the purpose of layered architecture.

Not to mention that it violates several principles of SOLID design.

In reality in professionally architected software your BL would interact with the DAL through interfaces in a loosely coupled fashion.  The BL would not know any implementation details of the data stores and would not care where the data came from. It would just be entities coming back from the DAL period.

Also by using DbContext directly from your BL you are mixing data access with business logic which violates encapsulation and single responsibility.

If you separate and encapsulate your DAL you can add any kind of data store without having to rethink your business logic layer.

Comment: _Your BL should never use DbContext directly and should not even know anything about it's existence_ That's really a matter of discussion. `DbContext` per se is an implementation of the unit of work pattern and `DbSet<T>` an implementation of repository pattern. Encapsulating it being a repository is difficult. On one side, you lose most of the advantages that come with it (i.e. up to .NET Core 3 you couldn't explose `IQueryable<T>` as you'd have to invoke it async (`.XxxAsync` Linq methods are EF core specific). On the other hand, EF Core is hard to mock/test in unit tests

Comment: So technically using EF Core from your business layer isn't mixing data access logic, as EF Core itself is persistance ignorant (it doesn't know which persistance is used in the background, be it Sqlite, Sqlserver, mysql, postgresql, oracle or a nosql db, in-memory or even something like a remote service or a file system serialization - If someone implementes such an provider). It mostly boils up down to testability. An `IUserRepository` or `IRepository<User>` is just easier to test and mock than an `DbContext`

Comment: It is a implementation detail an it is technically mixing data access logic.... There is a very simple question that will prove this.... Can you call DbContext from your BL without a reference to EF?  Of course you cannot.  This is called tight coupling.  And yes it is an implementation detail.  It goes against encapsulation no matter what pattern Microsoft followed it is wrong to use it directly.  As for being "unable to call it async" that is just not true.  You could make your repository async if you wanted.

Comment: Calling something "asyc" should be the choice of the caller in any case.  And lastly you admit this is an anti-pattern when you admit that "it is hard to mock/test in unit test".... Yes it is and the reason is because it is an implementation detail that causes tight coupling and dependencies in the wrong direction. Furthermore things like navigation properties or updating simple properties can trigger sql queries being fired from the BL or even worst from layers even higher in the system like the UI.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you use those static data.

But my preference is to always keep DBContext reflect exactly your DB, so it's single responsibility. Hence, its easier to maintain.

Then I will put those static data in an "utils" folder in your logic layer. Or even put it in an "utils" project, if you have many projects in your business layer.

Comment: This breaks the pattern and data is not "utils".

Comment: What pattern do you mean?

Comment: the pattern he is already using...!  Plus why would you call a data store "utils"? He has a very specific layered pattern... In which layer does this data store called "utils" go?

Comment: Like I put in the answer, it goes to logic layer. Because it is not data to be saved in db.

Comment: It just does not sound right.... It is not "logic". It is a data store so it should go in the DAL. This kind of situation is exactly what you want to prevent with layered design

Comment: To me it's logic, it explain what is CountryId you saved in DB.

Comment: it is pure raw static data.... it is actually in the first sentence of your answer "it depends on how you use those static data".... those are your words...so which is it? data or logic? you might want to update your answer to reflect that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Alex - Tin Le is correct, but here is the science why.

From a manufacturing perspective, a process should be separate from your bill of materials (BOM). The manufacturing order contains both the process and the act of selecting on-hand components.

Your controller action -- your order -- which consumes this data should therefore reference the instantiated hydrated CountryAndStates model prior to processing the user action. The database is definitely not a dictionary file for external data, which may come from files or even google web API calls. Store these classes in a separate folder and namespace from database models, so each component class can contain its own loaders if necessary. Naturally, you should standardize components with a base class so your controller can handle loading failures.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is what is called "Server side caching" that is a common practice for working with static data.

You can create a `static Dictionary<string,List<string>>` and initialize this dictionary in your application startup by reading the data from database or any other resources (you can even hardcode the data as you mentioned).

Then you can consider and treat this dictionary as a `datasource` and add functions to your data access layer for accessing the dictionary.

The obvious benefit of this approach is that performance is boosted.

Comment: I would not call this "server side caching" as one important aspect of caching is it can evict items when too much data is stored, I agree more with [Jonathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60591383/80274), however if you are going to use a server side cache, use a cache that has built in ability to evict items like a class that implements [IMemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Well! Definitely there are different technical ways for implementing a server side cache. The question though is asked from an architectural perspective and I was trying to fulfill that aspect. But thanks for your comment anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You could store the data in a resource file at application layer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/creating-resource-files-for-desktop-apps

Or you could reconsider and create a DB object for the data, and cache it at application layer